# OpenID Attribute Exchange - generated alias in FetchResponse causes loss of correlation to FetchRequest attribute alias

Tags: wso2, openid, wso2-identity-server

Requesting identity information using the OpenID Attribute Exchange Mechanism i discovered the following problem. The WSO2 identity server looses the correlation to the FetchRequest attributes alias. When creating a FetchResponse in OpenIDAttributeExchange#setAttributeExchangeValues(FetchResponse, Map) the method FetchResponse#addAttribute(String, String) is used. This method generates a new alias in the Response. Therefore a request like this (the attribute alias is "mail"):

```
openid.ns.ext1:http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
openid.ext1.mode:fetch_request openid.ext1.type.mail:email
openid.ext1.if_available:mail
```

Gets answered by WSO2 IS with a response like this (the attribute alias is "attr1"):

```
openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
openid.ext1.value.attr1=xxxx@xxx.com
openid.ext1.type.attr1=email
```

This loss of correlance causes problems. For example using Springs OpenID4JavaConsumer, actually none of the requested identity information attributes will be found in the response, because the OpenID4JavaConsumer uses the alias for the lookup.

Is it bug or what?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it yet?